# Django send object as json

Tags: json, django, django-haystack, paginator

Is there a way to send with json (or anything else other than render) an object_list made with paginator? The browser is making a getjson jquery request and the views.py function is supposed to return the object. The reason I want to return a json object rather than render a new page is because I don't want the page to reload

The following views.py code:

```
searchresults = form.search()#this is a call to a haystack form template
results = Paginator(searchresults, 20)
page = results.page(1)
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(page), content_type='application/json')
```

Gets this error:

```
TypeError: <Page 1 of 1> is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use django serialization https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/

```
from django.core import serializers
...
return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize("json", [q.object for q in results.page(1).object_list]), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'concrete_model'

Comment: Oh. I didn't see that you using haystack. It use another queryset format. So try that (edit answer)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dictionary that is serializable as @evilx commented or make your own Json by hand.